# Is there downtime while Scaling Azure SQL Elastic Pool Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I have an Azure SQL Elastic Pool with 800 eDTUs and 400GB of Storage.

In past, I used to have 400 eDTUs, and when I scale to 800 eDTUs I had a small downtime in the website (~15-30 seconds), so before making any changes to the storage, I'd like to check if I should expect downtime as well.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think don't need downtime when you Increase DTU's. Definitely, there is certain impact which you can read from [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-scale#impact-of-changing-service-tier-or-rescaling-compute-size)

> Regardless, the switch can result in a brief service interruption when
> databases are unavailable generally for less than 30 seconds and often
> for only a few seconds

Answer (score 2):

We do scaling real-time in eDTU's and DTU's and no downtime observed.
URL :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scale-resources

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback prasun. I forgot to mention that I am using Standard Tier.

Comment: I scaled up my DTU's from S2 to S4 and S4 to S6 during business hours and never noticed any downtime. 

Based on Ms Document:
You can change DTU service tiers or vCore characteristics at any time with minimal downtime to your application (generally averaging under four seconds).